# Send Push Notification via FCM when user is offline in MQTT?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service, mqtt, mosquitto

I want to run a background Mqtt service in Android, but from Android O background services will be restricted. So, I preferred to use Fcm. Is there any way in Mosquitto broker, if the user is offline in MQTT then it must publish to FCM to each user separately according to their topics.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Cloud IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot-core/) with [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) and [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to push the [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) notification.

that might also work with Mosquitto, if you somehow can connect Pub/Sub or Cloud Functions.

with FCM it's even possible to [subscribe to topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging), just alike in MQTT.

Comment: how could we use it for on-premise Mosquitto server ?